# How to add a selected value from cloudKit and display it in a view (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, cloudkit

I'm currently working on an app that has a function that adds a selected country from a search list retrieved from CloudKit. I got the search to work and the list to show and everything but I'm stuck at the part where the selected country will be added to the list.

To clarify my goal, I want this function to work similarly to the weather app on iPhone.
In order to add a city to your saved counties, you need to search the country and then select it to add it to the list of saved countries. I will attach some images at the end of the page for extra clarification.

I'm new to this whole Swift thing and I'm trying to sharpen my skills in it. I tried to look for documentation regarding this very thing without success. I would appreciate some help.

This is my code

```
    import SwiftUI
    import CloudKit

    struct addCity: View {
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showingNatio = false
    @State private var showingNotifi = false
    @State private var country = ""
    @State var em :[Emergency] = []
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var selectCountry: FetchedResults<CountriesList>
    @State private var shoeingAddscreen = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack() {
            
            NavigationStack {
                VStack{
                    List{
                        ForEach(selectCountry, id: \.self){ cont in
                            Text("Name \(selectCountry.count)")
                            city(cityPic: "france" , cityName: cont.country)}
                        
                    }.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                }
                Spacer()
                    .navigationTitle("Countries")
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .toolbar{
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                            
                            Menu {
                                Section {
                                    Button(action: {}) {
                                        Label("Edit List", systemImage: "pencil")
                                    }
                                    Button(action: {
                                        showingNatio.toggle()
                                    }) {
                                        Label("Edit Nationality", systemImage: "globe.asia.australia.fill")
                                    }
                                    
                                    Button(action: {
                                        showingNotifi.toggle()
                                    }) {
                                        Label("Notification", systemImage: "bell.badge")
                                    }
                                }
                            }label: {
                                Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                
                                    .frame(width: 22)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: 330,  alignment: .trailing)
                                    .padding(.top)
                            }
                            
                        }//ToolbarItemGroup
                    }//toolbar
                //.searchable(text: $searchText)
            }.searchable(text: $searchText) {
                ForEach(array) { emergency in
                    //Text(emergency.Country).searchCompletion(emergency)
                    HStack{
                        Text(emergency.Country).searchCompletion(emergency)
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            var slected = emergency.Country
                            let cont = CountriesList(context: moc)
                            cont.country = emergency.Country
                            
                            try? moc.save()
                        } label: {
                            Text("Add")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal).frame(maxWidth: 390)
                }
                // NavigationStack
                
                
            }.onAppear{
                fetchEvent()
                
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingNatio) {
            Nationality()
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingNotifi) {
            Notification()
        }
        
    }//vstack
    
    
    var array : [Emergency]{
        searchText.isEmpty ? em : em.filter{$0.Country.contains(searchText)
        }
    }
    func fetchEvent(){
        em.removeAll()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType:"Emergency", predicate: predicate)
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.recordMatchedBlock = {recordID, result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let record):
                let emer = Emergency(record: record)
                em.append(emer)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
        
    }
    
    func fetchSpecific(){
        em.removeAll()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType:"Emergency", predicate: predicate)
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.recordMatchedBlock = {recordID, result in
            switch result{
            case .success(let record):
                let emer = Emergency(record: record)
                em.append(emer)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        
        CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
        
    }
}
struct addCity_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        addCity()
    }
}
struct city: View {
    
    @State var cityPic = "france"
    @State var cityName = ""
    @State private var country = ""
    @State var em :[Emergency] = []
    //@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var countries: FetchedResults <CountryList>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        ZStack (alignment: .leading){
            
            Image(cityPic)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 360, height: 100)
                .cornerRadius(7)
                .overlay( Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .cornerRadius(7)
                    .opacity(0.4))

            Text(cityName)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .bold()
                .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded))
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
            
            
        }.padding(.horizontal,40)
        
    }
}
struct Emergency: Identifiable{
    let record: CKRecord
    let Country: String
    let id: CKRecord.ID
    
    init(record: CKRecord){
        self.record = record
        self.id = record.recordID
        self.Country = record["Country"] as? String ?? ""
        
    }
}
```

**Here the user seraches throught the cloud then selcts the country to add it.**
[image: search]

**Here the selected country will be added to the list**
[image]

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: @AshleyMills I attach my code to the question